# Synchronize custom column state between Area Paths in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have a VSTS project based on the Scrum process with two Area Paths for frontend and backend teams. For all Backlog item boards I created a new column to indicate what is 'ready for testing' (splitted in doing and done). For the state mapping I could only chose 'Commited' from the dropdown list.
The root area is configured to include both sub-areas and should provide a broad overview for the product owner about the progress and the tester to see what he needs to do.

My problem is, that when a team moves an item to this column, the change of state is not reflected on the general board. How can I achieve this? Or what are best practices to deal with additional states like 'ready for deployment' and 'ready for test'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kanban board states are "per team" so you won't see the change reflected in another team's board (in this case, the top level default team).

If this was on-premise we could add a new underlying State to the Work Item so it worked across teams.  I *believe* this is coming for VSTS but it's not there yet.

VSTS and TFS 2015 Update 1 allow you to [Query by Kanban board changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/query-by-workflow-changes) which means you could have a Work Item Query which shows all the items across teams that are Ready For Test on the board.

Depending on exactly what you want to see in your query results, you'll probably have to do something slightly clever with grouping the clauses of your query - ie. (PBI Area Path = Area 1 AND Column State = Ready for test) OR (PBI Area Path = Area 2 AND Column State = Ready for test)